# Send figure to printer in Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, printers

My Shiny (0.12.1) app creates the multiple page figures using grid package. Currently I save them into pdf file, then allow users to download and print them.

Is it possible to send the generated pdf/figures directly to the default printer? I have to specify two setting in the printer, i.e. 1) from two-side to one-side; 2) paper source from default to bypass tray.

It seems there are no R function for this target after googling. Or I have to use javascript to implement it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you'll have to go javascript or perhaps some other language to get this to work. I would be interested in the solution, though.

Comment: After a quick search in javascript. It seems there are no direct way to send file to printer in browser as the security reason.